# How to run cmd in spawn on nodejs

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd

I want to run cmd in the spawn, but when I run the command, you will not get a reply. 
How do I fix this?

```
var terminal = require('child_process').spawn('cmd', ['/K'], { timeout : 1000*60*60*24 });
terminal.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';
terminal.stdin.write(new Buffer('dir'));
terminal.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

terminal.on('exit', function (code) {
       // console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not giving return for command `dir`. In windows it is \r\n.

```
terminal.stdin.write(new Buffer('dir\r\n'));
```

This will work.

Comment: new Buffer is deprecated, use Buffer.from('hello world');